# WCF read MEX endpoint WSDL

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that has the contract published on a Net.Tcp MEX endpoint. I need to connect to the MEX endpoint and download the WSDL as XML. How can I do this? (I cannot move the MEX endpoint to HTTP... it must be on TCP).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The MEX endpoint is just an endpoint. Create a client for it, then issue operation calls</strike>

It looks like the correct way to do this is to use the [MetadataExchangeClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataexchangeclient.aspx).

Comment: Ok, so I created a client that connect to an IMetadataExchange endpoint but the only calls on the the contract are a Get that take a param of type Message. What goes in the message? I tried searching but there is no info on how to make that call.